# Do a ReFS fuse implementation exists?

Tags: linux, debian, centos, fuse, refs

Are there any plans on developing a fuse fs so that ReFS will be mountable and writable under linux ( debian and centos ) at least ?

Comment: Does it need to be fuse? Paragon offers drivers. https://www.paragon-software.com/home/refs-linux/download.html

Comment: @rudimeier the goal would be also able to write on that fs because the paragon driver is read-only as far I know. If some developer would be able to write one could be nice for the linux community :)

Comment: I don't see that the paragon drivers are read-only.

Comment: Looks like it's gone from Paragon's website since June 2018. anyone knows where to get them?